# Managed package patches - can a public inner class be added?

Tags: managed-package, patch, inner-class

In the [Create and Upload Patches](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=patches_creating.htm&type=5) documentation, there is no mention of restrictions on adding inner classes to an already packaged top-level class. The restrictions listed are:

- You can’t add package components.
- You can’t delete existing package components.
- API and dynamic Apex access controls can’t change for the package.
- No deprecation of any Apex code.
- You can’t add new Apex class relationships, such as extends.
- You can’t add Apex access modifiers, such as virtual or global.
- You can’t add new web services.
- You can’t add feature dependencies.

Can a `public` inner class be added to a managed package patch version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. We have taken this approach with our managed package when back-porting features to patches that added new top-level classes in our master branch. Obviously there are limits to what can appear in an inner class compared with a top-level one, but we have avoided such difficulties with minor refactoring.

Comment: Yep it is this situation I am in. Thanks for the confirmation: hate to do the work and then hit a gotcha at the end.