# Managed Package Upgrade Strategy for Beta Versions or Promote Version

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package, versioning

I'm currently working on developing a managed package and have encountered challenges with the upgrade process for Beta versions. When attempting to install a Beta version of the managed package in an org, it seems that upgrading isn't supported, and the package must be uninstalled before a new version can be installed.

However, the "uninstall before installing a new version" approach doesn't seem practical or good to me. I'm exploring alternative strategies, and one idea is to promote each version of the package.

I have a few questions and concerns:

- **Impact of Frequent Promotions**: Will promoting each version of the package have a negative impact on the org, and are there any best practices or considerations I should be aware of when doing this frequently?
- **Staging vs. Production Orgs**: My package goes through various stages, including staging and production. While most versions are for staging, a few make it to the production org. Is it okay to promote version only install in staging org and this is even might not go through produciton org
- **The limitation APIs**: There is limit on promote version. Only 80 times/day might kinda low for staging org [image]

I'm looking for guidance and insights into how to manage the package upgrade process effectively, especially during the development and testing phases. Any advice or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience , I can advise below points :

1. Will promoting each version of the package have a negative impact on the org ?

- No , frequent upload of managed packages does not have any documented impact on the org.

2. As a best practise , upload managed package when it's going to be installed/upgraded to production.
3. If there are minor changes without any breaking changes ([Answer covering limits of patch orgs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301479/can-an-auraenabled-method-be-added-in-a-managed-package-patch-release)) , prefer to upload a patch instead of complete package.
4. Whenever something is being deprecated, major changes in components are added , it is a good practise to increment the major version number (e.g. from `1.4` to `2.0`)
5. I would recommend to stick to a major release number (after freezing major changes like component additions/ access modifier changes etc.) and then uploading patches for small , frequent changes.
6. After development is completed , you can perform UAT using beta packages. (*generally UAT will not have upgrade dependency*)
7. You can typically freeze the major version number after UAT and then work with patches for fixing subsequent integration & upgrade testing issues.
8. Once package is ready , you can release the last patch to production or appExchange.

Salesforce recommends to use [2GP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm) packaging but it has some [gaps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_known_limitations.htm) compared with 1GP.

Comment: ohhh thank you for advising me. Sound like I need to research and integrate versioning in workflow to enhance it

Thank you so much, I appreciate it

Comment: @vctqs1 : Yes , having  CI/CD helps in release process. 2GP is more friendly from CI/CD perspective.

Comment: Also, having question from me. As I searched, the patch update also limit in some specific changes. so in that case. we should provide a minor instead, is it?
Also w patch update, we dont need do promote version. right?

How about if I increase `build` in major.minior.patch.build? Do it work?

Comment: If by promotion you mean listing on appExchange or using on production , it is optional to promote major/patch version.Also , I doubt we can have numbering like `major.minior.patch.build` for 1GP package. Also , the last number is always the patch number. It can't be build number. For 2GP , [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_upgrades.htm) doc gives some insights.

Comment: ohmm about creating new version number, I'd like to do something automation on CI/CD, there are any ways or cli, that able to auto-detect the changes and create correctly version number with patch or minor or major? something like this?

Comment: There are many automation tools like copado , gearset etc. I cannot tell a specific one since that would count as promotion of a product. You can explore different options and try it.

Answer (score 1):

Beta versions exist to allow you to make experimental changes in your managed package. These changes get "baked in" to the package, in an irreversible way**, when you include them in a managed release (for 2GP, when you promote a beta that includes the changes).

**: with 2GP you can create "branches" of your package, and those different branches may contain entirely different changes. Of course it is not possible to upgrade an installed version from one branch with a version on a different branch, so effectively resulting in much the same behaviour as per 1GP beta releases.

Installed betas cannot be upgraded because the changes in them may not be included in any other version. This also applies to cross-branch scenarios, as above.

However, for testing purposes, it is best to use betas since you *may* discover significant design issues that require a change that cannot be done in a compatible manner.

Such beta testing works best if you step away from the concept of fixed orgs for staging/testing and adopt scratch orgs. As with scratch org based best practice development, you create a scratch org for each version you want to test with. Unlike dev scratch orgs, it is necessary to use an unnamespaced scratch org so as to mimic a subscriber org.

Since you use a scratch org (with org shape and/or scripting to help you finalise org configuration, including data setup), you never need to upgrade a beta - you simply create a new scratch org with the alternative version.

The key is then that you only promote versions that have been tested and that would go towards production.

Patch versions can be treated identically, using betas initially and subsequently promoting the fix version.

NB: Patching 2GPs requires the package to have passed security review, since Salesforce Support will only enable this capability once it has been through that review process.

Here's an outline of how we work with package development:

1. We use namespaced scratch orgs on a per-developer, per-task basis. These scratch orgs are created to last at most the length of the development sprint. We do this to:

   - Allow us to deploy/push the metadata from the task's related git branch quickly and easily.
   - Ensure that the scratch org is clean, only including the metadata from the task's related git branch. This avoids cruft being on the org that could affect behaviour and that isn't in the git branch.
   - Be compatible with some of the oddities around certain metadata (I'm looking at you, Flow, and you, Aura) that require explicit namespace references without the need to mangle the metadata during deployment.
2. We use namespaced scratch orgs for QA for each task. We do this to:

   - Ensure the org contains just the metadata from the git branch to be tested.
   - Avoid the need to create beta releases of the product for every task. We just deploy/push the metadata.
3. We use no-namespace scratch orgs for QA regression testing before release of a new version. Here, we:

   - Use beta releases (of the new version or a patch, as relevant) and install these on the org.
   - Can ensure that we don't have unexpected behaviour for packaged metadata compared with deployed metadata, in an environment that is closer to a production org in structure and content.

To support this, we created some tooling including:

1. Scratch org creation and metadata population, including some "unpackaged metadata" (such as perm sets and some testing/demo configuration).
2. Test data import/export plugin for the SF CLI. This allows QA to have specific data for their manual tests.
3. JEST UI component testing.
4. UTAM UI end-to-end testing.
5. Demo data generation for randomized exploratory testing or quick demos.

Only once we have developed and QAed individual tasks do we then create a beta release for regression testing. Only after we pass regression testing do we promote for version release.

Comment: `NB: Patching 2GPs requires the package to have passed security review, since Salesforce Support will only enable this capability once it has been through that review process.`

So this mean we can not do patch update unless we contact Salesforce support to enable, is it?

Comment: `Patch versions can be treated identically, using betas initially and subsequently promoting the fix version.` so it mean with patch version, we still need to do something like `sf package version promote`, is it?

Comment: Yes, patches are also created as betas that must be promoted (2GP).

Comment: And yes, patching is enabled by Salesforce Support and you do this through a case. But only after passing security review.

Comment: ohmm, but my app have not distributed in AppExchange yet, we still need to contact Salesforce Support to do that?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317448/2gp-managed-package-cannot-create-a-patch-release?rq=1 I found your issue here, I also meet that, but just one small issue. even with create major version with `ancestorId` setted, this also found issue with package validation like u

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412458/picklist-value-advertisement-in-picklist-accountsource-not-found

Comment: Yeah, it's quite confusing. And then to find a known issue - just makes packages harder to handle...

Comment: Ohm I see, thank you

Comment: Ohmm, so what do you do to handle your development workflow with 2GP package in development environment and staging environment.

Comment: with mine, development org is a place will be deployed if having any PR merged for developer testing
staging environment like place PM and QA go there to do some demo and explore the features

Comment: We always use scratch orgs for all package development and testing - there's no worry about whether the package is beta or not that way. For our "development orgs" - we have one per work item (we use Jira, so we have one per dev per Jira issue) - we use namespaced scratch orgs that are typically kept for 2 weeks (length of a sprint), and our "staging environments" are namespaced scratch orgs per work item created by QA (or PM, in principle). For regression testing, QA creates no-namespaced scratch orgs and install the (beta) package. We have test and demo data tooling.

Comment: oohh create new development org per Jira issue kept it 2 weeks as a sprint sound like interesting for me. Do you have any specific reason or advances behind that why u decided to do that?